# Sort an arary of objects by date

Tags: javascript, sorting

I got an array of objects which I want to sort by date. I've got the date formatted like this with a property - `created_at: "2014-09-26 19:27:43"`.

If any one could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: [Have you read up on how the Array `.sort()` function works?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date` objects for **comparison** and `Array.prototype.sort()` to **sort**.

```js
var array = ["2014-09-26 19:27:43","2014-09-26 19:27:42","2014-09-23 19:27:43"];
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a,b){
       return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
    });
document.write(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Brillant, thanks for that managed to get it sorted..